# How to Clone Control in WPF?

Tags: wpf, clone

I want to clone a WPF Control (`XamDataGrid`)

I know these ways:

1. Clone
   Problem: Control is not Cloneable
2. Serialize & Deserialize in binary format
   Problem: Control is not serializable
3. Serialize as XML
   Problem: control contains images and Images are not serializable in xml serialization

Do you have any valid workarounds ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround

http://heskandari.blogspot.com/2009/07/infragistics-wpf-reporting.html