# How to make a clones for the buttons?

Tags: c#, user-interface, button, unity-game-engine

I need to *create the new button that allows to make the clone of buttons in the code below*, please share some ideas, codes, links, scripts. I'll be glad for any help. Thank you in advance!

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class hibye: MonoBehaviour 
{

    public string slectedItem = "fd";
    private bool editing = false;



    private void OnGUI()
    {   
        if ( GUILayout.Button(slectedItem))
        {
            editing = true;
        }

        if (editing)
        {
            string[] sig = {"Banana","Apple","Orange"};

            for (int x = 0; x < sig.Length ; x++)
            {
                if (GUILayout.Button(sig[x]))
                {
                    slectedItem = sig[x];
                    editing = false;    

                }
            }
        }


                }
            }
```

Comment: See if this helps you.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572066/how-to-clone-control-in-wpf

Comment: doesn't work for me at all, sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want to make a new button for Apple bannana etc the moment you click ?

try this:

```
for (int x = 0; x < sig.Length ; x++)
{
  GUI.Button(new rect(0,0,0,0),sig[x]));
}
```

for a clickable executable button use

```
for (int x = 0; x < sig.Length ; x++)
{
  if(GUI.Button(new rect(0,0,0,0),sig[x]))
  {
  }
}
```

hope this is of some use as it is a bit late ^^